# Can inputs into Neural Network be real-valued?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I am using a sigmoid function. My input values for all inputs range from .88 to 1.06. Is it okay to use real valued inputs in this range? Every example I have found on neural networks uses binary inputs. Also, because the inputs represent percent increases/decreases, should I subtract 1 from every input so the range is -.12 to .06?

Answer (score 3):

You can use real valued inputs for your neural network. It is however common practice to normalize them so that they are in the interval [0, 1] or [-1, 1]. Doing so saves you from numerical problems with the gradient that can lead to very slow learning. Common formulas to normalize input values are `v = (v - mean) / stdDev` and `v = (v - min) / (max - min)`, where `v` is one of your input values (one component in one input vector), `mean` is the mean of that component in your data, `stdDev` is the standard deviation of that component in your data, `min` is the minimum of that component in your data and `max` is the maximum of that component in your data.

E. g. `[0, 0], [2, 1]` might get converted to `[(0 - 0)/2, (0 - 0)/1], [(2 - 0)/2, (1 - 0)/1] = [0, 0], [1, 1]` (according to the second formula).